# Single word or phrase for 'refinement of shapes'

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

Is there a word or a phrase, describing the refinement (in the sense of *sophisticated and superior good taste*) of shapes in the context of some solid artistic works (such as pottery or sculpture)? I thought of *shapely*, but I'm not sure if it could be used in a non-suggestive context.

EDIT: The sentence, which contains the word or phrase should be: "The vase we've seen in the museum was amazing"—but with a word or phrase in place of "amazing" that describes the refinement of the vase's shapes with reference to its general shape and its relief details). That's one example that I can invent quickly, but it's going to be used regarding not vases literally, but some everyday things.

EDIT2: If you don't know such word or phrase, but have some thoughts regarding *shapely*, please share.

Comment: Please suggest a sentence where the word/phrase could  be used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Graceful** is often used to praise the contours of three-dimensional objects.

Comment: Seems to have peaked around 1900: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=graceful+curves&year_start=1600&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cgraceful%20curves%3B%2Cc0

Comment: Though it seems, that common adjectives are not enough creative for me, I'm accepting as this should be the closest one by meaning.

Answer (score 2):

**Elegant** When applied to inanimate objects, elegant implies refinement, beauty, and tasteful all at once, without any suggestive context.

[Link-MW](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/elegant)

Answer (score 1):

**Stylish**:  having elegance, taste or refinement (*mostly used in relation with fashion*).

**Harmonious**: forming a pleasingly consistent whole to ear, see, taste, etc